# Digital pulse converter from 3.5v to 10v

Tags: dc-dc-converter, level-shifting

I have flow meter generating pulses at TTL that is 3.5v. My pulse counter needs 10v pulse.
How can converter 3.5v pulse to 10v so that it can count.
Will DC to DC converter like here https://www.amazon.in/dp/B00V9ZF43S/ref=cm_sw_r_wa_apa_i_zqgqBbBWW6BD2 will work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to electronics.stackexchange.com. Please, clarify your question. Are you asking about 10V power supply (in your link) or about 3.5V to 10V level conversion.

Comment: And if it's about level conversion, have you considered solutions already posted on this site?

Comment: A DC-DC converter is for power, not for signals.  What you actually need cannot be determined without details like the signal rate and the input impedance of the 10v instrument.  Also, if it's allowable to invert the signal while amplifying it the circuit can be simpler than if it must remain uninverted.

Answer (score 4):

First thing: Amazon is not a good electronics supplier. You will notice that there is no datasheet available for that part and therefore you have no specifications for turn-on and turn-off time, etc., and no idea of component or build quality. Our recommendation is, "No datasheet? No sale!".

Possible problems with your idea:

- The board will require more power than the TTL driver can supply.
- The board takes longer to generate 10 V than your pulse duration.
- The startup waveform is jagged and gives multiple triggers to your counter.

Instead use a simple NPN common-emitter level-shifter. This will require a small current from your 3.3 V TTL driver.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTwiHI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. An inverting NPN logic-level shifter.*

Note that this will invert the logic.

You haven't given any detail on the pulse counter input. It may be that it has its own internal pull-up resistor in which case R2 may be omitted.

---

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fegRnb.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. High-side opto-isolator driver.*

Comment: Thanks for response. I do not want inverted pulse. I was going through other sites and found that Opto coupler can also be used. I was referring this url https://components101.com/ics/mct2e-phototransistor-optocoupler-ic But again here pulse is getting inverted. How can I avoid that

Comment: See the update.